# Unable to overscan at lower resolution with AMD ATI

Tags: ati, catalyst

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest ATI drivers installed. I have the catalyst option but I am unable to set overscan.

My default resolution is 1920*1080 on 15inch display. I want to set it to a lower resolution. But on setting it to any lower resolution the display shrinks i.e I see black chopped off display on the left and on the right :( Really frustrating this, wasted hours on this already.

I realized that this is referred to as overscan, but the ATI Catalyst Administrative just does not allow me to set the option. Can someone please through some light on this topic?